# HTML/CSS Input Button Styling Not Working

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button:

[image]
ON

[image]
OFF

Here's the CSS:

```
.searchButton {
  height: 31px;
  width: 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background:url(../img/searchButton-Off.png) no-repeat;
}

.searchButton:hover {
  height: 31px;
  width: 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background:url(../img/searchButton-On.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
  <div class="searchBox">
    <h2 style="color:000000;">Search</h2>
    <form id="form_297586" class="appnitro"  method="get" action="results.php">
      <input id="keywords" name="keywords" class="searchBar" title="What do you like...?" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
      <input type="button" class="searchButton" />
      <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="297586" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

Here's what my browser is rendering:

[image]
Safari
[image]
Opera

When I mouseover the button, it is correctly switching, and then will display the entire button. I'm not sure why this behavior is happening.

Thoughts?

Comment: My first guess is that something is going wrong with the styles, and the width of the text of the button is being used instead of the width you are defining in your stylesheet. What happens if you set a value on the button to put text in, like `value="test"` ?

Comment: Works fine here in Opera, Chrome, and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/63Lt7/. BTW I'd use a sprite here to prevent image flicker.

Comment: How would I do it with CSS sprites? I'm relatively new to CSS, so I have no experience with them.

Comment: And j08691, that's odd that it's working on jsfiddle. I'm not sure what's different about my code. Perhaps the error is elsewhere and something is being overridden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buttons have a lot of default styling attached to them. Consider implementing a reset stylesheet, like:

[Eric Meyer's Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

[Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)

Also, an element must be set to `display: block` or display: `inline-block` in order for dimensions to be able to be set on it.

Finally, I recommend that you put a simplified example of your problem into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com) so that it's easier for people to help you out.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Now that I can see your example, the problem is that the default styles in bootstrap.css have a higher specificity than your styles. Something like:

```
input.searchButton
```

Should solve the problem.

Comment: class="button.searchButton" ?

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bunch. I figured it was something like that.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a case of specificity, where a more specific set of conditions is taking precedence.

Try this:

```
.searchButton { 
  height: 31px !important; 
  width: 33px !important; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  border: none; 
  background:url(../img/searchButton-Off.png) no-repeat; 
}
```

Or you could try:

```
form.appnitro .searchButton {
```

Comment: !important seems to work. I'm still going to look into making it a sprite, but this fixed whatever the issue was. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

wrong!

you have

you have too use :

```
input[type=button].[class name]
```

or you can use:

```
<button class='x' ></button>
```

and Css:

```
button.x{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

background: url("../img/searchButton-Off.png") white no-repeat 9px;

just change 9px to any px and do it accordingly and also increase height:50px weight:50px

Comment: @Jon-can you put this code on jsfiddle.net and I will edit on it